# Select drop-down list possible to "Drop-Up"

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The `<select><option>foo</option></select>` drop-down is too close to the bottom of the page. I would like the drop-down to "drop-up". I have been searching but only able to pull up information on navigation menus. I tried giving the `<select class="select-store">` a top:100% and bottom:100% being position:absolute which is what I saw for navigation menu dropdowns to "drop-up" without prevail. Is this possible? Thank you guys in advance, code is below;

HTML

```
<select class="select-store" onchange="document.location.href=this.value">
  <option value="/">Store Finder</option>
  <option value="/foo">foo</option>
  <option value="/beta">beta</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
#finder .select-store{
  background: url("/images/storefinder_bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: medium none;
  color: #5B5A5A;
  font-family: UNIV-C,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 186px;
}
```

Comment: did you ever get this to work ?

Comment: We ended up having to add multiple more optins so it natively did our desired positioning

Comment: ah so because you had more options it wouldnt fit in a drop down so it dropped up instead right ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SELECT` element behaviour is determined by the browser. It alone detects overflow outside of the viewport and will sometimes reposition the list. You can't control this directly.

Now if you use a script-based simulated SELECT, the you can detect overflow in your the JS code and reposition accordingly.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the information. Even when I add another option it still dropsdown and is hovering on the bottom of the browser window but won't drop-up. Blasphemy!

Answer (score 0):

This is for selectize.js library. When you scroll the page to the bottom, then part of the options become unaccessible and ypu cannot scroll anymoe. This solution (combination of some googled code and mine) allows to automatically toggle drop-down and drop-up when the list starts hiding off the screen. In this case I got .footer element which is at the bottom of the page, but in front of all other elements, so the caculations are made in relation to ths element. Just add the code. It will be applied automatically to all selectize lists. In my project I am using jquery too. Remove `$(".footer").height();` if you want to detect bottom of the page.

```
if (!window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal) {
    window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal = window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdown;
    window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdown = function () {
        isInViewPort = this.isInViewport();
        
        if (isInViewPort) {
            window.Selectize.prototype.positionDropdownOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else 
        {  
            let $control = this.$control;
            let offset = this.settings.dropdownParent === 'body' ? $control.offset() : $control.position();

            this.$dropdown.css({
                width: $control.outerWidth(),
                top: offset.top - this.$dropdown.outerHeight(),
                left: offset.left
            });
        }
    };
}    

    window.Selectize.prototype.isInViewport = function(el) {
        let elementTop = this.$control.offset().top;
        let elementBottom = elementTop + this.$dropdown.outerHeight();

        let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height()-$(".footer").height();
        return elementBottom<=viewportBottom;
    };
```