# How can I control default behaviour of <select> element using js?

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I had to make a 'drop-ups'. So I googled and saw some stackoverflow articles and some blog posts about it. And usually they are about how to make 'select' element invisible and to transform it into 'ul li things' and compose them 'SELECT LIKE THINGS'.

What I want is simple. I just want to make my SELECT-BOX, Not select like things. I do not mean to underestimate those trials to make custom select-box but does it has to be list?

In my short experience, the html elements are controlled by browsers.

So.. long story short, Can I control default behavior of html elements like how the things are rendered on browser side using javascript(here in case select)?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919573/select-drop-down-list-possible-to-drop-up) is where my question is inspired. So if really i cannot control it directly then how can I manipulate it indirectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control how form elements like **select, input[type="radio"] and input[type="checkbox"]** will be rendered. You can control only catch events like focus, change, blur etc. Or set values and attributes.

**1)** To customize their view you can use js plugins, that hide original select for example and replace it with another, customizeable elements like **ul, li**.

**2)** You can use webcomponents (http://webcomponents.org/) to create your own elements, but then you must implement behaviors manually and forget about browser compability with older browsers

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto @AlmasK89's answer, form elements are controlled by the [system UI event](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#interface-UIEvent) according to the W3C spec.

You are able to style some properties of `select` elements such as `padding,font-family,font-size,background` through css, so you could potentially add or remove styles on that specific element using javascript.

Still, the short answer is no, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to achieve this. Try the following code:

HTML

```
<select id="myDropdown">      
    <option>Option 1</option>     
    <option>Option 2</option>     
    <option>Option 3</option>     
</select>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex
```

you will get the property by selecting the options, then you can customize it's property

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set it to fire any action via onclick javascript method